# How to create a multidimensional matrix in python with recursion

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, matrix, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have defined a function to generate a list of 6 random integers ranging from 0 to 10

```
import random
def func():
    randomlist = random.sample(range(11), 6)
    return randomlist
```

Run:

```
func()
```

Output:

```
[3, 7, 10, 9, 4, 1]
```

Now I want to define another function which calls func() inside with a parameter n to generate a multidimensional matrix, where each element will be replaced by a newly created list generated by func(), and n is the times of the completed replacement (so that the total number of integers in the matrix would be 6^n) -- for example --

when  n=1, expected result:

```
[3, 7, 10, 9, 4, 1]
```

when  n=2, expected result:

```
[[6, 2, 9, 1, 4, 0],
[7, 8, 1, 9, 4, 1],
[1, 0, 4, 6, 3, 1],
[9, 4, 3, 8, 6, 7],
[2, 4, 3, 9, 5, 6],
[4, 7, 2, 0, 1, 8]]
```

when  n=3, expected result:

```
[[[4, 7, 3, 0, 2, 8],[1, 5, 6, 5, 4, 8],[8, 9, 6, 5, 10, 4],[7, 8, 6, 6, 4, 10],[7, 8, 1, 0, 2, 3],[4, 5, 8, 5, 4, 6]],
[[1, 7, 2, 0, 2, 8],[4, 5, 8, 8, 4, 5],[9, 5, 6, 2, 1, 3],[5, 4, 1, 2, 6, 10],[7, 5, 4, 1, 1, 4],[9, 6, 5, 2, 2, 1]],
[[8, 2, 7, 10, 2, 7],[8, 9, 5, 4, 5, 5],[5, 8, 7, 7, 4, 6],[9, 5, 9, 10, 5, 4],[1, 4, 5, 6, 5, 7],[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 1]],
[[0, 7, 4, 0, 1, 9],[4, 7, 3, 0, 2, 8],[8, 9, 6, 5, 10, 4],[8, 2, 7, 10, 2, 7],[[7, 5, 4, 1, 1, 4],[7, 8, 1, 9, 4, 1]],
[[9, 5, 3, 9, 2, 8],[8, 9, 6, 5, 10, 4],[9, 4, 3, 8, 6, 7],[3, 7, 10, 9, 4, 1],[4, 7, 3, 0, 2, 8],[9, 4, 3, 8, 6, 7]],
[[5, 3, 4, 5, 2, 10],[[7, 5, 4, 1, 1, 4],[4, 7, 3, 0, 2, 8],[4, 5, 8, 8, 4, 5],[7, 8, 1, 9, 4, 1],[8, 2, 7, 10, 2, 7]]]
```

I think I'd need a recursive function, but I'm totally out of a clue. Any insights? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If your second function is `def n_dimensional_matrix(n):`,

Have you thought about what the base case will be? The base case is some condition in this function that causes it to *not* call itself, to avoid infinite recursion.

Then when the base case condition is not met, it will make a recursive call, but it needs to modify the `n` argument to move closer to the base case, again to avoid infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well base case of 1 is just to call your `func`, otherwise build a list of the recursion call on `n-1` `6^(n-1)` times:

```py
def recur_6(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return func()
    return [recur_6(n-1) for _ in range(6**(n-1))]
```

[Live example](https://onlinegdb.com/l6T-OvlGH)